# Minimum cpu frequency set when charging and battery under ~7%

Tags: intel, 19.10, cpufreq, scaling

I have i7-7500U (@ 2.70GHz) and the intel_pstate governor is used, I've noticed when the system has low battery (under ~7% or so) and ONLY when charging, the cpus run at the minimum frequency (400 MHz in my case), making  the system very sluggish.

When the battery reaches around 7%-10% the system behaves correctly. It's especially puzzling that charging when the battery is at low level slows down the whole system.

I've had this problem with 18.04 too, I though upgrading to 19.10 (clean install) would solve the problem but it did not.

How can I debug this?